# ckeditor not able to use custom config file

Tags: ckeditor

I have downloaded the latest ckeditor version 4.0.1. I am using this following code to set my custom config file.

```
    CKEDITOR.replace( textAreaId,
        {
            customConfig : 'suConfig.js',
            width : width,
            height : height,
        }
```

it is not considering the config file and while rendering my text boxes are empty without editor. But if i use the default config file it works

Comment: Check JS console. Most likely you've got an error.

Comment: Did you have an error? Any url to an uploaded example?